# How to make a navigation which reveals on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigation

I would like to create a navigation that reveals on hover however I am not sure how to go about doing it. I would like to do it how they have done it in the top left hand corner when you hover on the name: http://higz.ghosted.net/

I would like it to be just like the example and the menu which display to be a list so `<ul> <li>`

Comment: Not too sure what you want on the mouseenter event.  Do you want a menu to display or what?

Comment: I want a menu to display in <ul> <li> like the example

Comment: The answer is in the original source of the page just dig it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example related to what you are looking at- still there some issue you have to fix, but i have giving you the quick start.

final result -

http://jsbin.com/parok/4/edit?html,css,js,output

**HTML -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='navigation'>
    <div class='logo'></div>
    <div class='menus'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home page</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Service</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS -**

```
body {margin:0; padding: 0;}
#navigation {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: wheat;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
.logo p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.menus {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 40px;
}
.logo:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menus a:link, .menus a:visited {color: darkgray; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase;}
.menus ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.menus ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

**jQuery -**

```
$(function(){
  $('.logo').mouseover(function(){
    //console.log('foo');
    $('.menus').animate({
      'opacity': 1,
      'left': '20px'
    }, 500);

  }).mouseout(function(){
    //console.log('bar');
    $('.menus').animate({
      'opacity': 0,
       'left': '0px'
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use jquery and ajax if you want to do it Asynchronously. I prefer do it by calculating the navigation at run time using ajax provided they are not static pages. (depends on server side language you are using)**
Otherwise just use jquery to do this.

With the hover event of jQuery you show the navigation and on just hide it :

```
$("#id").hover(function(){
$("#id").show();
});

$("#id").mouseleave/blur(function(){
$("#id").hide();
});
```

***and do paste your code where you want to achieve it. Otherwise we can only put up theory here. We are not supposed to write entire code.***

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hard task to achieve..

Lets get started:

Step 1) Build a sample html content to be displayed on hover

```
<div class="toggle-display">
Your HTML
</div>
```

Step 2) Lets give it some css

```
    .toggle-display {
    opacity: 0.1; /*set to 0.0 to hide it completely */
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    /* transitions */
    -o-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear;
    }

    .toggle-display:Hover {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
```

3) Put it all together

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.toggle-display {
    opacity: 0.1; /*set to 0.0 to hide it completely */
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    /* transitions */
    -o-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}
.toggle-display:Hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="toggle-display">
Your content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4eq4D/)

Tried and works fine,

Hope this helped you (If so, mark this answer as ok please),
Best regards.

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

```
$('.blog_title').on('mouseenter', function(){
      $('ul').show();
});
```

In reality you want to animate and not just show().  It looks like the menu fades in and moves from the left.

Also you want to give your ul a class name otherwise this code will affect all the ul's in the HTML.

And you do the reverse on 'mouseleave'.